# xgboost ranking objectives pairwise vs (ndcg & map)

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, ranking

Im using the xgboost to rank a set of products on product overview pages. Where relevance label here is how relevant the rating given in terms of popularity, profitability etc. The features are product related features like revenue, price, clicks, impressions etc.

I am aware that rank:pariwise, rank:ndcg, rank:map all implement LambdaMART algorithm, but they differ in how the model would be optimised.

Below is the details of my training set.  800 data points divided into two groups (type of products). Hence 400 data points in each group. The labels are from 0-3 where 0 is no relevance, 3 is the highest relevance.

**x_train shape**

(800, 10)

**y_train shape**

800

**group_train**

[400, 400]

**labels**
[0., 1., 2., 3.]

Similarly, below is my validation set and test set.
**x_val shape**

(400, 10)

**y_val shape**

400

**group_val**

[200, 200]

**x_test shape**

(160, 10)

**y_test shape**

160

below is the model parameters I'm initially trying out

```
params = {'objective': 'rank:pairwise', 'learning_rate': 0.1,
          'gamma': 1.0, 'min_child_weight': 0.1,
          'max_depth': 6, 'n_estimators': 100}
model = xgb.sklearn.XGBRanker(**params)
model.fit(x_train_sample, y_train_sample, group_train, verbose=False,
          eval_set=[(x_val_sample, y_val_sample)], eval_group=[group_val])
```

The predictons look like below, which is what i expect.

```
7.56624222e-01,  3.05949116e+00,  3.86625218e+00,  1.57079172e+00,
4.26489925e+00,  7.92866111e-01,  3.58812737e+00,  4.02488470e+00,
3.88625526e+00,  2.50904512e+00,  3.43187213e+00,  3.60899544e+00,
2.86354733e+00,  4.36567593e+00,  1.22325927e-01,  2.79849982e+00,
```

But when i change the objective to rank:ndcg

```
params = {'objective': 'rank:ndcg', 'learning_rate': 0.1,
          'gamma': 1.0, 'min_child_weight': 0.1,
          'max_depth': 6, 'n_estimators': 100}
model = xgb.sklearn.XGBRanker(**params)
model.fit(x_train_sample, y_train_sample, group_train, verbose=False,
          eval_set=[(x_val_sample, y_val_sample)], eval_group=[group_val])
```

My Predictions go completely strange.

```
[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
   0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
   0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
```

Could some one help to know, why ?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: is this solved? Removing "gamma" does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue at first. Removing gamma works for me. You can try

````
params = {'objective': 'rank:ndcg', 'learning_rate': 0.1,
          'min_child_weight': 0.1,
          'max_depth': 6, 'n_estimators': 100}
model = xgb.sklearn.XGBRanker(**params)
model.fit(x_train_sample, y_train_sample, group_train, verbose=False,
          eval_set=[(x_val_sample, y_val_sample)], eval_group=[group_val])```
````